# Plotly chart has extra numbers on y-axis between the expected values

Tags: pandas, plotly

I have code that renders a plotly chart. When the y-axis is not logaritthmic the chart renders well. If I make the y-axis logarithmic then for some reason extra 2s and 5s appear on the y-axis.

Why do these 2s and 5s appear, how do I get rid of them?

[image]

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def render(users_df):
    users_started = (
        users_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="join_date", freq="M"))
        .size()
        .to_frame("user_count")
    )

    users_last_logon = (
        users_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="last_logon_date", freq="M"))
        .size()
        .to_frame("user_count")
    )

    users_ended = (
        users_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="estimated_end_date", freq="M"))
        .size()
        .to_frame("user_count")
    )

    union_dates = users_started.index.union(users_ended.index)
    users_ended = users_ended.reindex(union_dates, fill_value=0)
    users_started = users_started.reindex(union_dates, fill_value=0)

    users_active = pd.DataFrame()
    users_active["user_count"] = users_started["user_count"] - users_ended["user_count"]

    users_ended["user_count"] = users_ended["user_count"].astype(float)
    users_active["user_count"] = users_active["user_count"].astype(float)

    users_active_trace = go.Scatter(
        x=users_active.index,
        y=users_active["user_count"],
        name="Users active",
        mode="lines",
    )
    users_ended_trace = go.Scatter(
        x=users_ended.index,
        y=users_ended["user_count"],
        name="Users ended",
        mode="lines",
    )
    data = [users_active_trace, users_ended_trace]

    layout = go.Layout(
        title="Line chart with two series on the primary y-axis",
        xaxis=dict(title="x"),
        yaxis=dict(title="y", type="log", exponentformat="none"),
    )

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

    st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2's and 5's represent intermediary values between the powers of 10, ie.

```
[10^n, 2*10^n, 5*10^n, 10^(n+1), 2*10^(n+1), 5*(n+1), ...]
```

To get rid of them, you need to set `dtick=1`.

> [`dtick`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-dtick) : Sets the step in-between ticks on this axis. Use with `tick0`. Must be a positive number, or special strings available to "log" and "date"
> axes. If the axis `type` is "log", then ticks are set every
> 10^(n"dtick) where n is the tick number [...].

```py
    layout = go.Layout(
        title="Line chart with two series on the primary y-axis",
        xaxis=dict(title="x"),
        yaxis=dict(title="y", type="log", exponentformat="none", dtick=1)
    )
```